# git lfs fetch -all stuck when fetching non-lfs historical object

Tags: git-lfs

git lfs fetch -all output as follow:

```
...
12:28:46.546451 trace git-lfs: fetch Assets/GameLib/Editor/Log/Console.Editor.dll [325411bb444577bf87722995507c4b25e7f84ed2816019193be3b33be5f8ee0c]
12:28:46.546963 trace git-lfs: fetch Assets/GameLib/Editor/Log/Console.Editor.dll [a0c906d2e702bdc8b6860237f8be21a134e63bfcdf9bedf9cacd2c97ba53b15e]
```

[325411bb444577bf87722995507c4b25e7f84ed2816019193be3b33be5f8ee0c] is a lfs object, [a0c906d2e702bdc8b6860237f8be21a134e63bfcdf9bedf9cacd2c97ba53b15e] is not lfs object,  but git lfs fetch still want to fetch it then stuck witout error ouput, and other lfs objects aren't been fetched.

Because of these missing lfs objects, I can not do git merge!

```
Unable to find source for object 90af847f7266c61641eebac20fe6f5a884306429a7a6ca22cad732e580b97644 (try running `git lfs fetch --all`)
```

Is there any way to work around or fix this issue?

Comment: what does it mean "stuck"? How long do you wait?  Do you see any kind error message? Patience is a virtue.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've been waiting for at least ten minutes,  no error and any other message.